# PHP for a line break

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I currently have the below code outputting a custom field with a title and image but I'm trying to add a line break. As I understand it the `echo "/n";` at the end there should be doing the trick.

It's still outputting the data but with no line break - can anybody help out a rather hopeless case like myself :-)

```
 <?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_location2', true);
if( !empty($value)) {
    echo '<h5>Location</h5>';
     echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Address1.gif">';
    echo $value;
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: try with echo "<br>"; for line break

Comment: Do you need a line-break to make you HTML more readable or a normal HTML break to continue putting elements BELOW your `<img>` tag?

Comment: It's `\n` and not `/n`, but in your code it's correct. Did you try `PHP_EOL` instead?

Comment: "\" is a line break in the source code. <br> is an html line break.

Comment: `echo PHP_EOL;` will output a line break; `echo "\\n";` will output `\n`; `echo "<br />"` will output `<br />`, the html code for a line break.

Comment: hi can you mark this answer as accepted pls? thanks.. you just hover bside the answer and a checkmark will appear. Click it.

Answer (score 10):

Try [**nl2br**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

```
echo nl2br($yourTextData);
```

hope this helps

Comment: thanks so much for your help - it seems the echo "<br>"; as suggested above worked.